# Accessing variable from admin panel?

Tags: admin, options

I've created my own admin page in wp-admin folder using add_theme_page() function. How to pass variables from there to my blog? I mean what's the easiest way without arrays etc.

I've tried using "globals" but failed.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is very vague. If you're trying to implement theme settings check out `get_option` / `update_option`

Comment: Can you please give examples and use-cases for passing variables?  As @Ambitious Amoeba said, your question is too vague to get a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the codex page on [creating options pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages), and let us know if you run into any specific issues. It has a complete copy/paste example you can monkey with.

If you're trying to avoid learning WordPress' options mechanisms in favor of a more generic custom php solution, I understand where you're coming from, but recommend learning to do it the right way. It'll be a couple hours investment, but it'll pay off over time. For reals.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you get started

[10+ Rare WordPress Theme Options Page Tutorials To Get You Started](http://www.cssreflex.com/2010/02/8-fantastic-wordpress-theme-options-page-tutorials.html)